# Jackson naming convention issue in serialization with uncommon getter method name

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, javabeans, jackson2

New to java and spring boot.

While trying to serialize the following class,

```
public class ActionItems {

private String APpID; 

public String getAPpID() {
    return APpID;
}

public void setAPpID(String aPpID) {
    APpID = aPpID;
}

// other fields
}
```

got the json string as

```
{
"appID": null,     
}
```

Whilst, cross checking the getter name with decapitilize(), it is matching with the field name.

```
Introspector.decapitalize("APpID") - gives "APpID"
```

Is jackson using a different set of rules and methods when generating the property name from the getter method?

PS: I am aware that, variable name should begin with small case. While going through the java beans naming convention spec got this question.

**I am using jackson 2.9.3v.**

PS: As per the link [PropertyNamingStrategy](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html), it should have produced APpID instead of appId right?

Could someone provide some input here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jackson, you can custom [`PropertyNamingStrategy`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html), and

> In absence of a registered custom strategy, default Java property
>   naming strategy is used, which leaves field names as is, and removes
>   set/get/is prefix from methods (as well as **lower-cases initial
>   sequence** of capitalized characters).

Also, you can custom a property name like:

```
@JsonProperty("APpID") // produce {"APpID":"s"}
public String getAPpID() {
    return APpID;
}
```

Comment: If it is following the default naming convention, then it should have produced the field name as AppID and not appID right?

Comment: @NANDAKUMAR No, the default implemention has *lower-cases initial sequence*

Comment: Could you please add a link to it, so I can learn more about it. Thanks

Comment: @NANDAKUMAR The link is in my answer, also in your question. You can check it and see the sub class of  `PropertyNamingStrategy`.

Comment: Ah, thats great. Did not see the words inside the brackets. Thanks.